# How to send push request from server to all tabs on desktop

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, web, websocket

My application has the feature of authenticating the users by sending mail to their inboxes.

My question is, let's say he uses his computer to register and let's say he verified by clicking the link in his mail using his phone.

**How can I reload or redirect the tab on the desktop**?

**EDIT:**

*Form the comment I just made few research but need a worflow*

**Using websockets:**
I have two API endpoints in my application.

1. **/signup** -> register the user and store info in the database
2. **/verify** -> verify the email address

Once the user signup in my application he will receive a mail to verify and to achieve this I have two APIs which I have mentioned above.

My question is when I connect the user to the signup page and do the signup work, how to verify and disconnect the connection? because verification is done as a separate task!

Comment: Please change the tags, if you guess it helps!

Comment: You need to look into websockets.